# Table names containing the character 0xFFFF valid identifiers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

The MS documentation about [differences Between Compatibility Level 80 and Level 90](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb510680(v=sql.105)#remarks) is telling on Compatibility Level 80, "Object names containing the character 0xFFFF are valid identifiers", but which one are the character 0xFFFF can be naming for object name as table name,...?

Could you please help, thanks!

Comment: off-topic for SO - ask a [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Which part you don't understand there? I don't get your question really, the docs state clearly that _The object names containing the character 0xFFFF are not valid identifiers and cannot be accessed in compatibility level 90, and if you want to access it in compatibility level 90, you must rename objects that contain this character._ In the other hand _Object names containing the character 0xFFFF are valid identifiers and can be accessed in compatibility level 80_.

Comment: It's hard to know what you're asking.  I think that you've seen this change and you are wondering how it affects you.  You want to know if any of the identifiers in your database need to be renamed.   That being said, it is extraordinarily unlikely that any of the identifiers in your database have that character, unless your developers have gone out of their way to create, shall we say, cryptic identifiers.

Comment: Sorry about your confusing, I want to see an example about the character 0xFFFF in Object name, I'm thinking 0xFFFF is a 2 bytes character like some Japanese character.

Comment: It's not a printable character.   If you did have an identifier with that character, you wouldn't even be able to see it.

Comment: @DavidDubois yes, got it, but do you know how to naming an object with character 0xFFFF?

Comment: @DavidDubois your answer very make sense, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is extraordinarily unlikely that your database would contain any table or other object with an identifier with this character.  That being said, it can be done.
I used SQL Server 2008 to run the following script:

```
create database TestFFFF
go
alter database TestFFFF set compatibility_level = 80
go
use TestFFFF

declare @s nvarchar(200)

-- Build a string that will create a table
-- In our first example, we'll use a simple character
-- nchar(65) is the same as capital letter 'A'
-- so this will create a table named tungnAguyen.

set @s = N'create table [tungn' + NCHAR(65) + N'guyen] ( IDA int )'
exec sp_executesql @s

-- Now we will create a table name with character U+FFFF.
-- Note 65535 is decimal for hexadecimal FFFF.
-- Note this will only work if the database compatibility level is 80 or less.
-- Otherwise you'll get an error message.

set @s = N'create table [tungn' + NCHAR(65535) + N'guyen] ( IDF int )'
exec sp_executesql @s

-- Let's see if it worked.
-- I'll convert the table name to hexadecimal so you can see each character.

select name, CAST(name as varbinary(1000)) as BinName 
from sysobjects where name like N'tun%'

-- The result looks like this:
-- name        BinName                                    
-- tungnAguyen 0x740075006E0067006E00410067007500790065006E00
-- tungnguyen  0x740075006E0067006E00FFFF67007500790065006E00
--
-- The first row shows the first table we created using letter 'A'.
-- In the hexidecimal version you see 4100 in the middle.  That's the 'A'
-- 
-- In the second row, there appears to be nothing in the middle
-- of the name.
-- The reason is that character FFFF is not printable. 
-- In the middle of the hexidecimal you see FFFF.  This is proof
-- that the identifier contains that character.
--
-- Let's see if we can access these tables.
-- Start with the table that contains letter 'A'

set @S = N'select * from [tungn' + NCHAR(65) + N'guyen]'    
exec sp_executesql @S

-- It works. 
-- We've not inserted any rows, so the result is empty, but it works.
-- Now let's access the other table.

set @S = N'select * from [tungn' + NCHAR(65535) + N'guyen]'    
exec sp_executesql @S

-- This works too, as long as we are using compatibility level 80.
-- Let's change the compatibility level to 90 
-- and see what happens.

go
alter database TestFFFF set compatibility_level = 90
go

declare @S nvarchar(200)
set @S = N'select * from [tungn' + NCHAR(65535) + N'guyen]'
exec sp_executesql @S

-- This time it fails. We get an error message:
-- Msg 1055, Level 16, State 1, Line 73
-- 'tun...' is an invalid name because it contains 
-- a NULL character or an invalid unicode character.
--
-- The U+FFFF is the invalid Unicode character it is talking
-- about.  According to the Unicode standard there is 
-- no such character.
```